# Applying abbreviation to the column of a dataframe based on another column of the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, pandas-groupby, text-classification

I have two columns in the dataframe, one of which is a class and another is a description. In the description I have some abbreviations. I want to expand these abbreviations based on the class value. I have a dictionary with class as key and in the value I have another dictionary with abbreviations and its full form. Since these abbreviations mean different based on the class.
eg :- IT could mean ether Information Transport or Information Technology based on the class label.

I tried groupby, but was not able to get it back in the original dataframe.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

This is how I was trying:

```
grouped = df.groupby('class')
for n,j in grouped:
    j['description'].str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join([abb[n].get(e, e) for e in x]))
```

[image: example]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: I have added an image with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example that takes the row as input and looks up the `class` value in the dictionary, and replaces strings `description` with the corresponding value in the dict:

```
import pandas as pd

abb = {'IT':{'SQL':'Structured Query Language'},'Sales':{'SQL':'Sales Qualified Lead'}}

data = [{'class':'IT', 'description':'SQL developer'},{'class':'Sales', 'description':'senior SQL'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def replace_strings(row):
    text = row['description']
    for key, value in abb[row['class']].items():
        text = text.replace(key, value)
    return text

df['description'] = df.apply(replace_strings, axis=1)
```

|  | class | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IT | Structured Query Language developer |
| 1 | Sales | senior Sales Qualified Lead |

Comment: If you have many keys in abb, this wouldn't work

Comment: @mozway Why do you think so?

Comment: It looks like you have to type manually the abbreviation to replace (here "SQL"). If the dictionary has an arbitrary number of abbreviations, how would you map them?

Comment: @mozway Ok, I didn't get this from the provided sample, but I fixed the answer.

Comment: You can avoid looping through all the potential abbreviations. Imagine you have 1000 abbreviations, you code will loop over the abbreviations 999 times too many, parsing the string again for each abbreviation. This can have a bad impact on large dataframes.

Comment: @mozway No worries. I'll give you an upvote

Comment: That' was not the point here, just trying to get the best working solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
abb = {'IT':{'SQL':'Structured Query Language', 'BLAH': 'blah blah'}, 'Sales':{'SQL':'Sales Qualified Lead'}}

data = [{'class':'IT', 'description':'SQL developer'},
        {'class':'IT', 'description':'SQL developer BLAH'},
        {'class':'Sales', 'description':'senior SQL'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
   class                                    description
0     IT            Structured Query Language developer
1     IT  Structured Query Language developer blah blah
2  Sales                    senior Sales Qualified Lead
```

Code:

```
df['description'] = (df.groupby('class', as_index=False)
                     .apply(lambda x: x['description'].str.replace('|'.join(abb[x.name].keys()),
                                                                   lambda m: abb[x.name][m.group(0)]
                                                                  )
                           ).reset_index(drop=True)
                    )
```

output:

```
   class                                    description
0     IT            Structured Query Language developer
1     IT  Structured Query Language developer blah blah
2  Sales                    senior Sales Qualified Lead
```

Comment: Getting below error->
    KeyError: ('SQL developer', 'occurred at index 0')

SQL developer is the first element of description.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The problem I am facing with this is when assigning the value back to the original dataframe. It is not ordered. First one group is processed and their value is assigned to the dataframe.

eg : If there are 3 records -> IT,Sales,IT -> first IT is processed then sales group is processed and while updating the dataframe -> IT,IT,Sales value is updated instead of the original order.

Comment: Weird, it was working fine for me, anyway I made a slight change that should prevent index mismatch. Can you try again? NB. this solution should be more efficient than that of @RJ Adriaansen.

Comment: Still facing the same issue. Please consider below data for your testing.

    data = [{'class':'IT', 'description':'SQL developer'},
        {'class':'Sales', 'description':'senior SQL'},
       {'class':'IT', 'description':'SQL developer BLAH'}]